# C++: Vector of pointers vs Fixed-size array performance

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, game-engine

Performance-wise, which is faster?

A vector of object pointers allocated by the new operator?

```
std::vector<Object *> array;
```

Or an array allocated with new in the constructor?

```
Object[] objects;
objects = new objects[64];
```

The idea is that in every frame, the program loops through each element reading/writing values for each element.

Edit:

The second snippet was pulled from an XNA book. I am not using XNA to write my framework, and I'm trying to figure out the best method for using containers in an application that requires speed.

Comment: I don't see pointers in either, and I don't think the second code snippet is even valid C++. You might want to elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do because as is, the question is essentially only answerable with "yes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely the second one.

- With a vector of pointers, each individual element of that vector can be allocated anywhere on the heap.
- With an array of objects, all elements are stored sequentially.  This means the processor can cache chunks of memory more effectively as you iterate through the array.

The concept is called *cache locality*, referring to how well organised your data is with respect to memory access patterns and caching.

As pointed out in the comments, neither of your examples are correct.  I assume you meant something like this:

```
std::vector<Object*> vector_of_pointers(size);

Object *array_of_objects = new Object[size];
```

However, I fear you may not have phrased your question the way you intended.  You're not comparing two similar things.  A vector is basically just an array that can grow if necessary.  It makes all the same guarantees as an array, and so if it's storing the same data type, you shouldn't notice any difference between the two.

```
// Bad cache locality:
Object **A = new Object*[size];
std::vector<Object*> B(size);

// Good cache locality:
Object *C = new Object[size];
std::vector<Object> D(size);
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the difference is nothing to do with using a vector vs. using an array however, it is just about having objects contiguous in memory vs. pointers contiguous in memory. There would be no performance difference between an array of objects and a vector of objects, or between an array of pointers to objects and a vector of pointers to objects.

Comment: @mattnewport Yep thanks, I was already editing my answer with that in mind.

Comment: @paddy The size parameter for vectors is a new concept for me. When the size parameter is set, does that mean the vector is locked to that size indefinitely? What happens if you push back past the size limit?

Comment: @user3330642 No, it just constructs the vector to be that size initially instead of empty.